# Drag & Drop grid control to rearrange rows in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

I am looking for an asp.net server control which has a a drag & drop feature to rearrange the rows.

I have a table about article which i need to rearrange some times I am looking for a free control of code example which i can implement for such functionality.

I found one [example](http://aspdotnet-example.blogspot.com/2011/10/gridview-reorder-row-drag-and-drop.html). I hope if we already a free asp.net server control for such functionality.

Comment: See this: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/06/13/the-gridview-row-drag-overlay-extender.aspx

Comment: See this: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/06/13/the-gridview-row-drag-overlay-extender.aspx and http://aspdotnet-example.blogspot.in/2011/10/gridview-reorder-row-drag-and-drop.html

Answer (score 0):

You need more than just ASP.NET. You can use JQuery to rearrange the rows (drag-n-drop)